# Adjusting resolution between two raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis, resolution

I have two rasters with very slightly different resolution and the same number of cells. I need to adjust the resolution from one of the rasters (Raster 1) to match the other (Raster 2).

Is there a solution in GRASS?

Summary from Raster 1.

```
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Map:      Stream                         Date: Mon Feb 26 17:01:06 2018    |
    | Mapset:   PERMANENT                      Login of Creator: Guido           |
    | Location: newLocation                                                      |
    | DataBase: F:\M2 Stage                                                      |
    | Title:                                                                     |
    | Timestamp: none                                                            |
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |                                                                            |
    |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
    |   Data Type:    FCELL                                                      |
    |   Rows:         2810                                                       |
    |   Columns:      2535                                                       |
    |   Total Cells:  7123350                                                    |
    |        Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                      |
    |            N: 2:56:30.012N    S:  20:28:30S   Res: 0:00:30.000004          |
    |            E: 58:28:59.988W    W: 79:36:29.988W   Res: 0:00:30             |
    |   Range of data:    min = 47295  max = 301894                              |
    |                                                                            |
    |   Data Description:                                                        |
    |    gnr par r.in.gdal                                                       |
    |                                                                            |
    |   Comments:                                                                |
    |    r.in.gdal -k input="F:\M2 Stage\Topography\Stream_Raster.tif" output\   |
    |    ="Stream" memory=300 offset=0 num_digits=0                              |
    |                                                                            |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Summary from Raster 2.

```
      +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      | Map:      Direction                      Date: Mon Feb 26 17:02:25 2018    |
      | Mapset:   PERMANENT                      Login of Creator: Guido           |
      | Location: newLocation                                                      |
      | DataBase: F:\M2 Stage                                                      |
      | Title:                                                                     |
      | Timestamp: none                                                            |
      |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
      |                                                                            |
      |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
      |   Data Type:    FCELL                                                      |
      |   Rows:         2810                                                       |
      |   Columns:      2535                                                       |
      |   Total Cells:  7123350                                                    |
      |        Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                      |
      |            N:   2:56:30N    S:  20:28:30S   Res: 0:00:30                   |
      |            E:     58:29W    W:  79:36:30W   Res: 0:00:30                   |
      |   Range of data:    min = 1  max = 128                                     |
      |                                                                            |
      |   Data Description:                                                        |
      |    gnr par r.in.gdal                                                       |
      |                                                                            |
      |   Comments:                                                                |
      |    r.in.gdal -k input="F:\M2 Stage\Topography\Direction_Andean.tif" out\   |
      |    put="Direction" memory=300 offset=0 num_digits=0                        |
      |                                                                            |
      +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `r.region` does it. You can either set it from a raster (Raster 2), the current region or the default region, there are more, it is plenty of options.

In your case, it could be like this:

```
r.region map=Stream raster=Direction
```

Man page: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.region.html